# What are the best cold-storage methods available for XTZ?

Tags: security, hsm, wallets, setup, cold-storage

Is using the CLI command `gen keys new` to generate a cryptographically secure key-pair the most secure method for cold storage eg. paper wallet? Which signature algorithm (ed25519, secp256k1, p256) should be used and what are the benefits/drawbacks for this purpose?

Or is storing the XTZ on a Ledger hardware wallet the best/secure option? Are there other alternatives available for cold storage?

Comment: Question is overly broad and a matter of opinion. Please ask specific technical questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hardware wallets like the Ledger Nano are good cold storage solutions.

Offline-wallet creation in an air-gap device is also a good solution.

Kukai wallet offers you the possibility to do offline-signing so your seed is never exposed to the online world when interacting with the network.

Comment: "ledger" and "nano" are both refering to the device "Nano S" by the company Ledger. You probably meant "Ledger" or "Trezor" (the main competitor)